# Getting file by file located in a folder

Tags: c#

I got a folder that contains millions and millions of files (under windows server2012), and, using Directory.**GetFiles** needs a lot of times to get all these files,

I am just wondering if there is any c# method that can return **file by file** instead of getting all these files at once,

(just like an `SQLDataReader` and using `while (reader.Read())` to get line by line within DB)

Comment: you can use ``EnumerateFiles`` method

Comment: thank you Ehsan, do you have any small example or a link ?

Comment: @Souregi it is not really a big task. Use your favorite search engine and type 'EnumerateFiles' and you will find all the examples you like

Comment: @Souregi use the same code you used to enumerate the results of `GetFiles`

Comment: Please read [ask] and show that you researched this before asking a question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: thanks for all the duplicates.

Comment: it worked like a charm, thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(yourPath);

foreach (var fi in di.EnumerateFiles())
{
     Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
}
```

You can use [**DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns an enumerable collection of file information in the current
>   directory.
>
> Return Value Type: `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FileInfo>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)) {
    //access your files
}
```

Comment: _"try something like this"_ - try explaining why.

Comment: People can try a lot. An answer should not contain "try". It should contain reasoning why it works